# Python Panda Concat Multiple Rows

Tags: python, sql, csv

I am using the following code to create a merged Panda DataFrame.

```
mergedPanda = indicatorPanda.merge(commentPanda, on='id', how='left')
```

But I am having an issue with duplicate rows with the same ID because of multiple lines in the Dataframe2

So now, here's what I want my end result to be:

**DataFrame 1**

```
ID  VALUE        DATE
1   google.com   12/28/2015
2   yahoo.com    12/28/2015
3   cnn.com      12/28/2015
4   facebook.com 12/28/2105
```

**DataFrame 2**

```
ID  COMMENT
1   Bad Stuff
1   Much Worse Stuff 
2   Good Stuff
3   Werid Stuff
4   Crazy Stuff
```

**And the desired result will be here**

```
ID   VALUE        DATE          COMMENT
1    google.com   12/28/2015    Bad Stuff | Much Worse Stuff
2    yahoo.com    12/28/2015    Good Stuff
3    cnn.com      12/28/2015    Weird Stuff
4    facebook.com 12/28/2015    Crazy Stuff
```

Is there a way to just concat the comments onto each other with some sort of character? I know we are out of the realm of regular SQL and Panda.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do a `groupby` on the second frame first to get the pipe-separated version you want and then just merge it with the first:

```
In [27]: df1
Out[27]:
   ID         VALUE        DATE
0   1    google.com  12/28/2015
1   2     yahoo.com  12/28/2015
2   3       cnn.com  12/28/2015
3   4  facebook.com  12/28/2105

In [28]: df2
Out[28]:
   ID           COMMENT
0   1         Bad Stuff
1   1  Much Worse Stuff
2   2        Good Stuff
3   3       Werid Stuff
4   4       Crazy Stuff

In [29]: df2.groupby("ID").agg(" | ".join)
Out[29]:
                         COMMENT
ID
1   Bad Stuff | Much Worse Stuff
2                     Good Stuff
3                    Werid Stuff
4                    Crazy Stuff

In [30]: df1.merge(df2.groupby("ID").agg(" | ".join), left_on = "ID", right_index=True, how="left")
Out[30]:
   ID         VALUE        DATE                       COMMENT
0   1    google.com  12/28/2015  Bad Stuff | Much Worse Stuff
1   2     yahoo.com  12/28/2015                    Good Stuff
2   3       cnn.com  12/28/2015                   Werid Stuff
3   4  facebook.com  12/28/2105                   Crazy Stuff
```

Comment: Yes! Thank you, I've been banging my head at this for a while now. So many awesome things you can do with Pandas. Marking answered!